Transpose nested Tables individually before expanding within Column
I want to transform a column in power query whereby each cell in the column is a table. I want to transpose those tables individually before expanding the column.
Here is what I have tried, but it throws an error -
Expression.Error: The parameter is expected to be of type Text.Type or Binary.Type.
Details:
    [Table]

let
    Source = SharePoint.Files("https://jenson1.sharepoint.com/sites/Portofolio/", [ApiVersion = 15]),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(Source,{"Content", "Name", "Folder Path", "Extension", "Date accessed", "Date modified", "Date created", "Attributes"}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Reordered Columns", each Text.Contains([Folder Path], "/Completed Investments/Active/")),
    #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Rows", each ([Extension] = ".xls" or [Extension] = ".xlsm" or [Extension] = ".xlsx")),
    #"Filtered Rows2" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Rows1", each Text.Contains([Name], "Database_Management_Accounts")),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Filtered Rows2",{"Content", "Name"}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "Custom", each Excel.Workbook([Content])),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom", {"Name", "Data", "Item", "Kind", "Hidden"}, {"Custom.Name", "Custom.Data", "Custom.Item", "Custom.Kind", "Custom.Hidden"}),
    #"Removed Other Columns1" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Expanded Custom",{"Custom.Data"}),
    #"Invert" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Removed Other Columns1", {{"Custom.Data", each Table.Transpose(Csv.Document(_))}})
in
     #"Invert"


If your column contains a Table, why are you using the Csv.Document function in that line?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Hi Ron, Thanks for responding. The code I "wrote" come from several YouTube videos that I have looked at and cobbled together. Do you think that could be the source f the error? if so then what function should I use for tables. Thanks

It is rarely a good idea to post code when you don't know what it is doing. And you have chosen to not include a data sample by which we can reproduce your problem, so I would be just guessing. But I'd think something like Table.TransformColumns(#"Previous Step Name", {{"Relevant_Column_Name", each Table.Transpose(_)}}) might work, although you might need to include a step to demote/promote headers.

Thanks Ron. I have now solved it. found the solution here ... https://www.bing.com/videos/riverview/relatedvideo?q=power+query+nested+tables&&view=riverview&mmscn=mtsc&mid=0780B42CF9CEF56E90460780B42CF9CEF56E9046&&aps=32&FORM=VMSOVR

You can add a custom column with the transpose function on your column with the table. Example:
    let
        Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("Lc25DQAgDATBVpBjAh7zhdAGcv9tAMclK020e8t0UbysW/NPCUpUhjKlkFIFKlSFKtWgRnWoUwMaVAx/H8TsAA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [#"Col 1" = _t, #"Col 2" = _t]),
        Tbl1 = Source,
        Tbl2 = Source,
        #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(Tbl1, {"Col 1"}, Tbl2, {"Col 1"}, "Tbl3", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
        #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Custom", each Table.Transpose( [Tbl3] ))
    in
        #"Added Custom1"

